# How can I present Facebook messenger app in activity controller view to send a message?

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-messenger

```
    func pickerView(sender : UIButton) {
    let message="text"
    let objectsToShare = [message]
    let wsActivity = WhatsAppActivity()


    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: [wsActivity])
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypePrint]

    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How can i do the same thing with Facebook messenger ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as my research went, you cannot share "string" in FB messenger. This has something to do with FB messenger policy (lost link ref for this). In order to share on Facebook messenger, your "activityItems: objectsToShare" should contain an NSURL. I have tried sharing multiple NSRULs and it did not work out.

You can pass an array of [String, NSURL] for example:

```
func pickerView(sender : UIButton) {
     let message="text"
     let url = NSURL(String: "https://www.google.com")!
     let objectsToShare = [message, url]  //this is now an [AnyObject]
     //assuming you are don't have applications to exclude

     let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: [wsActivity])
     self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

You will find both whatsapp and FB messenger showing up in your share sheet. However, FB messenger will only use the NSURL its, and ignore the String item in the AnyObject Array. WhatsApp will show the text followed by the link.

You *might* be able to do what you want to do using the FB SDK. I have not tried it personally though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present facebook app in `UIActivityViewController`
than not specify any `excludedActivityTypes` property .

Because `excludedActivityTypes: [String]? //default is nil`.`

so just use as

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: [wsActivity])

self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

it will show you all option including facebook , twitter ext.

Comment: There is still no Facebook messenger

Comment: FB messenger needs special arrangements for its "objectsToShare". It is simply unable to share what you want to share. Check their policy.